# Xcode 4.6.1 crashes whenever i try to add my device to the provisioning portal.

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.6, xcode-organizer

Xcode 4.6.1 crashes whenever i try to add my device to the provisioning portal through Xcode Organizer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here's the solution:

1. Exit Xcode.
2. Run the following commands in Terminal:

   > mkdir ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/OldPortalDBs; mv
   >   ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/connect1.apple.com*
   >   ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/OldPortalDBs
3. Start Xcode and try again!

For more details, see the official post on [Apple Developer Forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/796388#796388).

Comment: Thats Great. Worked for me. Never know it would be this easy. Thanks Attila

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely a bug in Xcode. Was working fine in the past. The command does not work for me either. The directory ~/Library/Developer/Xcode not found. Any advice, please. It is interesting, my new iPad was added without any problems. Cannot add iPhone to provisioning profile. iPhone runs iOS 6.1.3, iPad 6.1.2. It seems Xcode 4.6.1 does not support iOS 6.1.3

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a bug in Xcode. I have a similar problem - it crashes when I refresh the provisioning profiles in the `Organizer` - every time. I ended up doing everything through the provisioning portal them manually downloading the profiles and updating them in Xcode.

Comment: I would suggest you to try the aove solution by Attila.

Answer (score 0):

~/Library/Developer/Xcode/connect1.apple.com*   No such file or directory;

Oh my god, what's the problem.

==========

**update**

the answer did not work for me, after all, I cleaned all the related informations in keychain, and all provisioning files in Xcode, and renewed all these files, fixed this issue